# wp_handle_upload - The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2012/09

Tags: php, uploads

This is the code I am using to upload the file to WordPress

```
define(‘WP_DEBUG’, true);

$filename = "test.png";
$tmpFile = download_url("http://url.com/testing/crop/".$filename);

chmod($tmpFile, 0755);

$mimeType = wp_check_filetype($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/testing/crop/'.$filename);
$file_array = array(
    'file'      => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/testing/crop/'.$filename,
    'url'       => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/testing/crop/'.$filename,
    'type'      => $mimeType['type'],
    'size'      => filesize($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/testing/crop/'.$filename),
    'name'      => $filename,
    'tmp_name'  => $tmpFile
);

$image = wp_handle_upload($file_array, array('test_form' => FALSE, 'test_upload' => FALSE, 'test_type' => FALSE));

print_r($file_array);
print_r($image);

unlink($tmpFile);
?>
```

This is the error I am getting "The uploaded file could not be moved to /home/xxxx/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2012/09."

What I am trying to do is have a small PHP script outside of WordPress upload images to its Media Library and then post it however at this point I am getting stuck at the uploading stage.

All the permissions are correct as I am able to upload fine through the WordPress admin area.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why don’t you use a local path for the temporary file? PHP cannot copy a file to a HTTP URL.

Comment: A local path is being used "download_url" returns "/home/xxxx/public_html/wp-content/test1.tmp"

Comment: And `url` is not an URL but a local path too?

Comment: url isnt being used in this instance. After looking into the error here http://wpseek.com/wp_handle_upload/ it seems to be failing at "if ( false === @ move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'], $new_file ) )" for the life of me I can't work out why its failing to move the uploaded file then it throws the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `move_uploaded_file` function is a PHP function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

One important thing to note about it from that page:

> This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is
>   a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST
>   upload mechanism). If the file is valid, it will be moved to the
>   filename given by destination.

You're not uploading a file here, you're downloading it from a URL, saving it locally, and then attempting to use `wp_handle_upload` (which uses `move_uploaded_file`) to handle it. This fails because it's not actually an uploaded file.

What you're actually trying to do is called a "sideload", where you get a file from URL and load it in directly. WordPress has a function for this specific case, called `wp_handle_sideload`. For the specific case of images, WordPress has another function called `media_sideload_image` that does much the same thing but also handles all the image processing.

If you really are wanting to upload files and not sideload them from a URL (this could be test code you're trying to do), then you need to code up a file upload form, get the contents of the `$_FILES[0]` parameter, and pass that to `wp_handle_upload`. If you're trying specifically to handle uploaded images or other items for the media library, use `media_handle_upload` instead. Uploads through these function have to be real, not faked.